# Android Firebase and google service latest version conflicts

Tags: android, firebase

I am use the latest version for individual dependencies.
Versions are referenced from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

But I am still getting warning message of conflict versions.
Not sure if it is safe to use like this.
Images attached below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can update same version all play services dependencies and solve the issues

Comment: Yes I can down grade all dependencies to same old version.
But my question is why I cannot use latest version.

Comment: update class path in gradle
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

Answer (score 0):

Also try to remove your custom libraries from project and sync project. Old versrions of libraries can be used by them.

Comment: Tried no luck, the version conflict comes between different firebase modules